# A 90% fade visibility of a full stable Google Maps image behind any front image, no matter the application

Tags: google-maps, redmi, background-process, overlay

I have a Redmi 10 Pro phone.
There is an image of Google Maps that remains permanently behind any image in front, no matter the application.
That image is about 90% fade from a normal image.
It does not appear on a screenshot action.

Restarting or shutting down does not help.
Also changing the background image does not help.

Any suggestion on how I can erase that image?

Comment: Check whether [toggling PiP on Google Maps](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/248916/44325) helps or not.

Comment: If the Google Maps ghost image remains even after a reboot then it is a ghost image cause by AMOLED burn-in. This is because that image was shows for a very long time and brighter pixels age faster (do you use the phone often for navigation?). This is a physical effect that can not be reversed, except by replacing the screen.

Comment: Especially that the Google Maps image is not visible on a screenshot is a clear indicator for an OLED burn-in problem. See also https://android.stackexchange.com/q/216169/2241 and https://android.stackexchange.com/q/249380/2241

Comment: Thank you, Robert! Yes, i use Maps for many hours on a ride. Not every day, but long enough, anyway... It seems that i must change the phone...